# Entity Framework Bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature of Entity Framework.

I created 2 tables without Ids. I don't see these tables in my diagram but if I try remove all tables, Visual Studio shows me the table names.[image]

Comment: I don't use the designer much, but they're not hidden underneath another table or off screen? i.e. zoom to fit doesn't zoom out to show them.

Comment: I check the zoom. The table doesn't exist on diagram.

Comment: I can't remember where I read it, but if there is no ID I think they're set up as a navigation property...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a many to many relationship that relationship is modeled in the database by using a table to do the mappings between the two tables. It is likely your table was turned in to one of those "look up" tables.

So something like this
[image]

Turns in to this
[image]

Comment: Additionally, Entity Framework is not always a 1 to 1 mapping.